# Print the content of an uploaded file in perl

Tags: perl, file-upload

I made a small script in perl that displays the content of a file sent by a user.

However I noticed something strange: if the file is named `0`, nothing will be printed, like if I didn't send any file and just refreshed the page.

1. How can this happen?
2. Is there any risk of someone dropping in the filename command to make my server execute it? (with the pipe thing)

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

if ($cgi->upload('file')) {
    print '<h1>file uploaded:</h1>';

    my $file = $cgi->param('file');    
    while (<$file>) {
        print "a";
        print "<p>".$cgi->escapeHTML($_)."</p>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Because the string `0`, like the empty string and the `undef` value, evaluate to false in a boolean context like

   if ($cgi->upload('file')) { ... }

In filenames and text processing, this is an edge case that is usually less trouble than its worth to think about, but when you do need to worry about it, the workarounds are to evaluate whether the input is an empty string or not

```
if ($cgi->upload('file') ne '') { ... }
if (length($cgi->upload('file'))) { ... }
```

2. Early versions of the CGI module open the temporary file with `sysopen` and modern versions use `File::Temp`. Either way is sufficient to ensure that Perl is attempting to open a real file and will not use a shell that can be tricked by pipes or backticks into executing an arbitrary command.

Answer (score -1):

I would probably use autoEscape ().

Another option is to simply test for the file name being "0" and asking the user to change it if it is.

Also, you could use temporary filenames.

See the official CGI documentation for more information.
[CGI Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html)

Comment: Although this is some interesting information, this is not an answer.